# vue async function returns [object promise]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, es6-promise

**UPDATE**

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-glade-vq1e5?file=/src/mixins/permissionerMixin.js)

**What i try to do:**

i am working on a permissionerMixin which should handle a websites permission for authenticated users.
for example if a logged in user has no permission to see a specific part of the website i handle the components with a `v-if="allowedToSee"`. So far so good. i store the whole user permission object in my vuex store.

the data came from a rest api and looks like this:

```js
const rights = [
  {
    name: 'findMe1',
    value: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'findMe2',
    value: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'findMe3',
    value: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'findMe4',
    value: false,
  }
]
```

**now back to my mixin and and how i load the data from the api:**

```js
import axios from 'axios';
export const permissionerMixin = {
  methods: {
    async getRightsFromActiveUser() {
      axios.get(`/not/the/real/path/${this.$store.state.User.activeUser.id}`)
        .then((response) => {
          return this.$store.commit('addActiveUserRights', response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response);
        });
    },
    async permissionFor(rightName) {
      const rights = await this.getRightsFromActiveUser();
      for (const right of rights) {
        if (right.name == rightName) {
          return right.value;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as u can see i have two functions which work together.
`getRightsFromActiveUser()` is simply a getter for the right object i mentioned at the beginning.
it takes the actual data and puts it in the vuex store with a mutation:

```js
const state = {
  activeUser: {
    id: 0,
    permissions: {}
  }
};
const getters = {};
const actions = {};
const mutations = {
  addActiveUserId (state, id) {
    state.activeUser.id = id;
  },
  addActiveUserRights (state, rights) {
    state.activeUser.permissions = rights;
  }
};
export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

right after this we have the actual init function `permissionFor(rightName)` which should do the magic and should give me a boolean return value to handle the permissionings.

the one big problem now is that i instead of getting a boolean return, i get a `[object Promise]`, thats because i am stupid and i don't get that promise thing in my head.

at the end i simply want to add this function to a vue component with an

`v-if="permissionFor('whatEver')"` to solve the permission handling.

Comment: i have your code open and the first thing i see is mixing chained promises .then() with async/await. I would say pick one and stick to it. The second thing that messes with me is `return this.$store.commit('addActiveUserRights', response.data);` Your returning the actual commit. Should you be storing AND returning maybe? I'll put that in an answer for you to see and it may help. I have never tried to log the return from a commit to see what it gives you.

Answer (score 1):

pulled the return into it's own statement following the commit. Not sure what your response object looks like from the back end but this look a cleaner to me personally and able to be read later. Check it out and see how things change, if at all.

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const permissionerMixin = {
  methods: {
    async getRightsFromActiveUser() {
      try { 
        let returnData = await axios.get(`/not/the/real/path/${this.$store.state.User.activeUser.id}`)
        this.$store.commit('addActiveUserRights', response.data);
        return returnData.data
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
      }
    },
    async permissionFor(rightName) {
      try {
        const rights = await this.getRightsFromActiveUser();
        for (const right of rights) {
          if (right.name == rightName) {
            return right.value;
          }
        }
      } catch(error){
        console.log(error.response);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what did you get?

Comment: still the same `[object Promise]`

Comment: what do you get if you console.log the returnData.data object directly AFTER the axios call?

Comment: i get the requested data but the code also goes into the `permissionFor() -> catch(error){console.log(error.response);}`

Comment: i try to do a CodeSandbox

Comment: that would be perfect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216007/discussion-between-goofballtech-and-deniz).